# Using an object from another project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, object, constructor

I want to send or be able to access the database from within the window code, so I was thinking of adding a constructor on the main window and sending the context from the Program class, where I show my window and load the database, but the context is in the program project, and I'm already referencing the window project, so I can't have circular references

I have two projects, one for the GUI, and another one with all the classes including the Context for an entity framework database

```
class ProgramControl: DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Asignaturas> Asigns { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Alumno> Alumnos { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Profesor> Profes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Aula> Aulas { get; set; }




}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new ProgramControl()) {
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static MainWindow AppWindow;


    public MainWindow()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AppWindow = this;

    }

    private void AlumnoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 window1 = new Window1();
        window1.Show();
    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void AsignaturasButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 window2 = new Window2();
        window2.Show();
    }

    private void ProfesorButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window3 window3 = new Window3();
        window3.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program class should normally be part of your GUI project (which also has the window class). Then in your GUI project you only have to reference the db (context) and not vice versa which removes the circular dependency.

Also, you call a constructor of MainWindow with a parameter db (instance of ProgramControl; entityContext) which is not in your code?!

Comment: Yeah, I removed the constructor when editing the post and forgot to remove it in the Program class. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, did you try the proposed solution?

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks!